# Triangles and a square

Tags: geometry

You have a square. Can you form an odd number of identical triangles inside the square so that the whole square is covered by triangles? Below is an example of 2 and 4 identical triangles.

Can you prove/disprove it?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this question for any odd cases at all, for example $n=3$?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: Do we have to assume that triangles do not overlap?

Comment: [Monsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem)